# angular material tab customization using class

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I have done my mat-tab customization as follows

```
.mat-tab-label {
     font-weight:300; 
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:white !important;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity: 1 !important
}

.mat-tab-link {
    color:white !important;
}

.mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: white !important
}

.mat-tab-label-active {
    font-weight:300; 
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:white !important;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity: 1 !important
 }
```

the tab looks as

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Sales">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100%"> </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Service">
    <h1>Some more tab content</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I have two problems:

1. the ink-bar color is not changing
2. I have two different tab groups. I want to style them differently. So with above solution, it basically changes all the tab components globally. How do I convert them to specific CSS classes?  I did try like `.my-label` and using it as `class="my-label"` but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use [::ng-deep](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459) to override default css properties.

So your CSS becomes:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
     font-weight:300; 
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:white !important;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity: 1 !important
}

:ng-deep .mat-tab-link {
    color:white !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: white !important
}

ng:deep .mat-tab-label-active {
    font-weight:300; 
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:white !important;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity: 1 !important
 }
```

Regarding the second point of your question, simply wrap these CSS properties in different classes and use them where needed.

Comment: what do u mean by wrap? i usually do .my-label {copy page same from .mat-label}  and use class="my-label"  is that same or doing it differently ?

Comment: Yes i meant exactly that

Comment: this is hard for tab cases as there are no direct elements like ink-bar in tab component that i can add my own class